# 'CHECKPOINT_SHUTDOWN' Log Entries in PostgreSQL During Master-Slave Replication and Server Failures"

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication, failover, postgresql-14

In a master and slave setup, I documented the WAL (Write-Ahead Logging) file changes. During the promotion of the slave, a log entry named "checkpoint shutdown" appears in the master's log file. I am seeing this log message only during promotion. I have a doubt in this, If an intentional crash of the master PostgreSQL server is attempted, will the "checkpoint shutdown" log entry be recorded in the failed master's log file? Is it possible that this particular log file is transfered during promotion of slave (From failed master to promoted slave)? Will this "Checkpoint shutdown" occur in any other scenario?

The log entry:
rmgr: XLOG        len (rec/tot):    106/   106, tx:          0, lsn: 0/03000140, prev 0/03000108, desc: CHECKPOINT_SHUTDOWN redo 0/3000140; tli 1; prev tli 1; fpw true; xid 0:569; oid 24576; multi 1; offset 0; oldest xid 561 in DB 1; oldest multi 1 in DB 1; oldest/newest commit timestamp xid: 0/0; oldest running xid 0; shutdown
It is recorded in Failed master's log file